# Open Command Prompt from Java

Tags: java, windows

I have the following code to open a command prompt window `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");`, but I'm trying to open the prompt with a different location loaded into it.

The idea behind the program is to allow the user to choose one of 3 options to load the command prompt window into, and they're mounted on different locations for example two of them are `X:/myJava/` and `H:/publicJava/`.

How can I open the command prompt window that is loaded into these folders once the user makes their choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start", null, new File("X:/myJava"));`

Comment: then set this as answer!

Comment: I have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0):

You can use making a batch file with commands like 
`x:
 cd publicJava`

and then execute that batch file using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myBatch.bat");`

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start /d d:\\java");
```

The start command accepts a path via the "/d" switch. Keep in mind that you have to escape the backwards slash in the path, hence the double slash.

Comment: I managed to figure it out and got it to work with this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start", null, new File("X:/myJava"));`

Comment: I updated my answer to include the Java bit. That will work for you without the need to create a File instance. Though it's not that big of a deal.